# javascript not recognizing .fbx file type

Tags: javascript, mime-types, fbx

i have to validate an `<input type="file" />` html field in which is only possibile to upload .fbx files, but javascript is not recognizing this `MIME-TYPE` (it returns an empty string), there is any way to do so?

This is what i get:

```
lastModified:1497968051479
lastModifiedDate:Tue Jun 20 2017 16:14:11 GMT+0200 (CEST)
name:"headset.FBX"
size:669984
type:""
webkitRelativePath:""
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

FBX is not supported by mime-type. This is one of the limitations. You can convert the file to .stl and pass the Mime type "application/vnd.ms-pkistl". This will work.

Comment: but i think is only a javascript problem, `PHP` is recognizing `.fbx` as `application/octet-stream`, thanks anyway

Comment: "application/octet-stream" this works for me, I have added in IIS

Comment: application/octet-stream means that the mime type is unrecognized, it doesn't identify FBX files in particular.

Comment: I'm facing almost same issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538119/windows-server-2019-returns-404-for-fbx-file

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old thread, but let me share my research. FBX does not have mime-type, but it does have standards (every year comes out new one). Also there is ASCII FBX and binary version. If you want to serve it, just use `application/octet-stream` and if for some reason you want to do something with it at website like here https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fbx#webgl_loader_fbx you have to use something else eg. extension to identify it's fbx.

Comment: if fbx does not have mime-type then how can I download it from url(windows server iis)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538119/windows-server-2019-returns-404-for-fbx-file

Answer (score 0):

`<input accept=".fbx,application/octet-stream" type="file"/>` works